# ¿ como definir el ancho de EditorFor?

Tags: bootstrap, mvc, asp

tengo este código en la vista:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fecha)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fecha)
```

y en mi modelo:

```
public class SaldoCursoParaleloParam
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una Fecha Valida")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

mi EditorFor esta definido de tipo dateTimerPicker

lo que quiero saber es como puedo definir el ancho.

porque me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***No quiero usar JQuery o JavaScript***

Comment: Que version de MVC utilizas?

Comment: hola, estoy utilizando el MVC 4.0.0.0

Comment: EditorFor se traduce a HTML como input y el proyecto de ASP.Net por defecto lo establece en su css con un ancho del 100%. Más bien revisa el maquetado que has echo, puede que tengas algun error en tu Grid. O puedes ir a Site.css y en input establecerle el ancho ke prefieras. Te recomiendo que pongas mejor el código de la vista de tu formulario en esta pregunta.